# Exact same python code 20 times slower on faster machine?

Tags: python, performance

I am trying to execute the following python code which will return alphabetically the first permutation of "ABCDEGGHIJK" which it would take a very simple sorting algorithm as defined in Project Euler problem 336 the greatest number of iterations to sort.

Here is the code (apologies for the bad variable names):

```
from itertools import permutations

def first_out_letter(st):
    """
    returns the first letter alphabetically  in st which is not in    sorted order
    alphabetically, string must be all in captials.
    """
    def first(string):
        """
        returns the first alphabetical letter in a string, only capitals allowed
        """
        alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

        for i in alpha:
            if i in string:
                return i
        return None
    sor = ''.join(sorted(st))
    for i in range(len(st)):
        if st[i] != sor[i]:
            return first(st[i:])
    return None

def get_arrangement_size(arrang,dictionary):
    """
     returns the number of shifts needed to arrange a string in lexographic order
    using a dumb method of first getting the first digit correct, then the second
    and so on...

    the argument dictionary stores precomputed results and is modified during execution. 
    """
    if arrang in dictionary.keys():
        return dictionary[arrang]
    sor = ''.join(sorted(arrang))
    if arrang == sor:
        dictionary[arrang] = 0
        return 0
    else:
        bing = first_out_letter(arrang)
        num_arr = 0
        pos_bing = 0
        for i in range(len(arrang)):
            if arrang[i] == sor[i]:
                num_arr += 1
            else:
                break
        for i in range(len(arrang)):
            if arrang[i] != bing:
                pos_bing += 1
            else:
                break
        if bing == arrang[-1]:
            low = get_arrangement_size(arrang[:num_arr]+arrang[num_arr:][::-1],dictionary)
        else:
            low = get_arrangement_size(arrang[:pos_bing]+arrang[pos_bing:][::-1],dictionary)
        dictionary[arrang] = low+1            
        return low+1

solutions = {}
letters = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K"]
piv = permutations(letters)
for item in piv:
    get_arrangement_size(''.join(item),solutions) #builds up the solutions dictionary
ma = max(solutions.values())
fir = []
for item in solutions.keys():
    if solutions[item] == ma:
        fir.append(item)
fir = sorted(fir)
print(fir[0])
```

The code works fine on both my machines and gives the correct answer but I am seeing a very large speed difference of up to 20 times on my two machines.

My (theoretically) faster computer with an i5 is running Linux Mint and python 2.7.6 and has more memory as well but when I run this code I find that it executes much slower than on my slower computer which is a Celeron with Windows and python 3.5.1 . I am not running anything else simultaneously when I run this code on either of my machines and they both use the same IDE (Spyder) so I have no idea why there is this speed difference?

Any help or reasons to explain this would be much appreciated.

EDIT: As according to Chriss' Suggestion I tried running this code on python 2.7 on my slower computer and it was also much slower than when I ran the code on 3.5 on the same computer. So this difference is caused by the python version but exactly what is it that causes the difference I don't know and would still like to know.

Comment: Have you tried Python 2.7 on Windows, or Python 3.5 on Linux?

Comment: @Chris . I Just did and it turns out that python 2.7 on windows was also much much slower than the python 3.5 so I guess that this difference is because of python version. However exactly what causes this difference I still do not know and would like to find out.

Comment: This could be because of differences of `range` between Python 2 and Python 3. Could you try to convert all `range` calls to `xrange` and run it on Python 2 to see if it helps? I'd do it myself but the original code results to memory error on my machine...

Comment: @niemmi I have tried changing all the range to xrange and it does not make any significant difference. Also If you want to run the code try reducing the number of letters in the variable letters (so say A,B,C,D,E,F only in the letters variable).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is caused by difference of `dict.keys()` between Python 2 and 3. In Python 2 [`dict.keys()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys) will create a copy of the keys as list and return it. In Python 3 [`dict.keys()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys) will return [`dictionary view`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views) instead which is `set` like object. Checking if an element can be found from `list` is much slower than checking if it's in `set` which explains the difference.

If you make following change the code runs roughly in the same time on Python 2 & 3:

```
if arrang in dictionary: # Instead of if arrang in dictionary.keys()
    return dictionary[arrang]
```

Comment: Thank you, this works very well. However if I want to check if an element exists the values of a dictionary I would have to use `if element in set(dictionary.values()): ` if I am not mistaken. Is this correct?

Comment: @AbdulHadiKhan: Yes, you could use that but it wouldn't any faster than only `element in dictionary.values()`. Both generating the `set` and checking if value is in a `list` have `O(n)` time complexity. If you need a fast check for both keys and values it's better to store the values to separate container, like [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) (`set` will do as well if you know that values are unique).